# Local path planner (dwa) has strange behavior

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, pathplanning, baseglobalplanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I am trying to let a robot with omni-directional drive (ridgeback) follow a global path generated with global_planner::GlobalPlanner from navigation package. I am using the ridgeback_gazebo simulation for this. The local planner is dwa_local_planner::DWAPlannerROS. I am using standard parameters for both global and local planners as well as the cost maps from ridgeback package (see [here](https://github.com/ridgeback/ridgeback/tree/kinetic-devel/ridgeback_navigation/params)), but also tried to modify multiple parameters. However, I get the strange behavior that sometimes the robot stops even if no object is near and turns on point. This can be seen here at 0:20  : [Video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Yg74QgshSwZLkYRd9).

I would love to know why this occurs. I also tried TrajectoryPlannerROS and set the weights such that following the global path has extremely high priority, but unfortunately with the same behavior.

Platform: Ubuntu16.04 with ROS Kinetic
Versions: Everything installed from apt in the last 7 days

Video description:
This is a recorded map from the ridgeback_gazebo standard simulation environment, yellow displays the global path, blue the local path and the local costmap can be seen. I am using amcl / map_server for localization.
Thank you for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305420/local-path-planner-(dwa)-has-strange-behavior/) by [JulienKindle](https://answers.ros.org/users/38000/julienkindle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
just did a quick look at your params and just had some minor advice on what you could adjust, to kind of improve.

First thing is the inflation layer:

inflation_radius: 0.25

This should be comparable to the full size the robot footprint, in your case (0.96 length and 0.8 width).

From how the costmap keep out and decay regions work having a small inflation_radius in comparison to the footprint is going to cause some problems when it tries to make that U - turn like movement in the global plan.

Further reading here: http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d

My recommendation is to try adjusting the parameters of the inflation layer like so:

```
inflation_layer:

 enabled:              true
 cost_scaling_factor:  0.3  # exponential rate at which the obstacle cost drops off (default: 10)
 inflation_radius:     1.0
```

If this doesn't solve your planning issue is it possible to post a screenshot or error messages that come up on the command line during the execution?

---

Originally posted by [shiv_rar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38001/shiv_rar/) with karma: 46 on 2018-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JulienKindle](https://answers.ros.org/users/38000/julienkindle/) on 2018-10-11**:
First of all, thank you so much for your help!

I modified the inflation layer params to your suggested params. This definitely helps. However, at certain angles, the behavior still occurs, even with inflation_radius: 2.0

[Screenshot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/W2mF2gZWYS6fsWaS8)

**Comment by [shiv_rar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38001/shiv_rar/) on 2018-10-11**:
Hey, maybe try reducing the update_frequency in the costmap configs to remove the warning and see if that helps to.